# How to make chart horizontally scrollable

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts

I am using this chart library  *https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.3.0/Chart.min.js"*
and I have success to show the chart data, but I cannot make it scrollable horizontally. How to make it scroll?
I've tried all the way

```
<div class="wrapper" style="background-color: whitesmoke; ">
    <div class="chartAreaWrapper" style="width: 550px; overflow:scroll;">
        <canvas id="myChart" width="1600" height="900"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

this one of them, and this the javascript

```
var years = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30];
// For drawing the lines
var africa = [86,114,106,106,107,111,133,221,783,2478];
var asia = [282,350,411,502,635,809,947,1402,3700,5267];

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'line',
data: {
    labels: years,
    datasets: [
    { 
        data: africa,
        label: "Africa",
        borderColor: "#3e95cd",
        fill: false
    },
    { 
        data: asia,
        label: "Asia",
        borderColor: "#8e5ea2",
        fill: false
    }
    ]
}
});
```

Comment: put overflow-x:scroll; on the canvas that you have a height specified on, it need the height restriction to work. you may also need overflow-y:hidden;

Comment: it doesn't work @CarolMcKay

Comment: it looks like the canvas already does scroll horizontally 
https://codepen.io/carolmckayau/pen/YJMpjZ

Comment: yes, but the problem why the chart cannot be scrolled, is it about the chart or the javascript side?